# How old is Matilda supposed to be?

Tags: matilda, matilda-2022

In [*Roald Dahl's Matilda the Musical* (2022)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3447590/), Matilda is played by Alisha Weir.

How old is Matilda supposed to be in the movie?

---

Alisha Weir was born Sep 2009 so would've been 13 when the movie was released around Dec 2022 and 11 when filming "took place in late spring and early summer of 2021" ([source](https://www.goodto.com/entertainment/where-was-matilda-the-musical-filmed-locations-behind-the-scenes)).

---

One clue is that Miss Honey says in class,

> So today is reading. ... Now, this book is actually for nine-year-olds, but you're all doing so well that I thought we'd give this a try.

(The book she hands out is [*The Railway Children*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Railway_Children).)

So, we can probably assume Matilda's classmates are under nine years old.

(Note though that Matilda is sent to school only after Miss Honey and a school inspector visit the Wormwoods and are not convinced she is being properly home-schooled. So we should not assume Matilda has necessarily been sent to a class of students of her age.)

---

Clarification as there seems to be much confusion (especially by those who haven't watched or even heard of the movie and so have no idea what I'm talking about):

As clearly stated above, I am specifically referring to the **2022 movie**.

And **NOT** the [1996 movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matilda_(1996_film)) or the [stage musical that first premiered on West End in 2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matilda_the_Musical).

(The 2022 movie is heavily based on but far from identical to the stage musical.)

Comment: Is there a reason you don't believe [what Wikipedia says about this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matilda_(1996_film))? Especially given it's stated very early in the movie itself, should you have watched it recently enough to wonder.

Comment: @Nij: Is there a reason you confused "Roald Dahl's Matilda the Musical (2022)" with "Matilda (1996 film)"?

Comment: @Nij - That's the wrong film reference. She's 5½ in the book, 6 in the first movie, 5 in the stage Musical & seemingly 'unspecified' in the 2022 movie [which I haven't seen.]

Answer (score 4):

In the [source novel](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/39988.Matilda) Matilda has just turned five at the start of the book, and is approaching five and a half when she goes to school for the first time.

> Most children begin Primary School at five or even just before, but Matilda's parents, who weren't very concerned one way or the other about their daughter's education, had forgotten to make the proper arrangements in advance. S**he was five and a half when she entered school for the first time.**

In the [1996 movie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matilda_(1996_film)) she confirms her age as six and a half.

> **Harry:** *The library? You've never set foot in a library. You're only four years old.*
>
> **Matilda:** ***Six-and-a-half***
>
> **Harry:** *You're four!*
>
> **Matilda:** *Six-and-a-half.*
>
> **Harry:** *If you were six-and-a-half, you'd be in school already.*
>
> **Matilda:** *I **want** to be in school. I told you I was supposed to start school in September. You wouldn't listen.*

Her age isn't explicitly stated in the [2022 musical](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3447590/), but in [the show-script for the musical on which it's based](https://myart.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/Matilda-Full-Script-pdf.pdf) her mother says that she's five years old. Matilda doesn't correct her.

> **MRS WORMWOOD:** *Look at this, she's reading a book. **That's not normal for a five year old.** I think she might be an idiot.*

Comment: The screenplay you linked to is for the musical (premiered on West End in 2011), not the 2022 movie (released on Netflix). The line you quoted (*That's not normal for a five year old*) does not appear in the 2022 movie.

Comment: @user24096 - See edit. Better?